# JavaScript not in list of Selenium Script Languages inside of JMeter

Tags: javascript, macos, selenium, jmeter

I am wondering if anyone has seen this issue in JMeter where JavaScript is not an option in the Script Language drop-down of the Selenium WebDriver? The only options available to me are the ones on the screenshot below.

I have tried with Selenium 3.3 and 3.0 and the drop-down does not change and this is on Apache JMeter 5.4.3 under macOS Monterey.

[image: Missing JavaScript option in JMeter]

Comment: If you look at the list. Those are all Java based languages: programming languages that compile to JVM bytecodes. The reason for this is that JMeter is written in Java and runs on the JVM thus any program you write in any of those languages can be compiled into a class and JMeter only needs to load the class. There is no flavor of javascript that can compile down to java. There is Rhino, a javascript interpreter written in java (kind of like node.js - it is javascript for servers) but that is different, it runs on Rhino, not directly in JVM

Comment: ... and therefore it cannot conform to JMeter's plugin architecture

Comment: Interesting that they don't support Clojure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the [Nashorn engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) which gave the possibility to run JavaScript from Java has been deprecated [removed from JDK](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) you need to consider one of the following options:

1. Downgrade your JDK to a lower version where Nashorn is still there (the minumum Java version which can run JMeter 5.4.3 is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/))
2. Switch to [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) which comes with JavaScript scripting engine
3. Switch to another language, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as it provides [maximum performance comparing to the other scripting options](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

Comment: Thank you, I took over a script from another person that is no longer in my organization and I just could not figure out why I wasn't able to run this script but downgrading the JDK solved this.